# Scale to fit option

Tags: microsoft-publisher

With Microsoft Publisher I have a document that is 16" x 20". I would like to print this on 11" x 17" paper, scaled to fit.

However when I select print instead of the normal option <kbd>One page per sheet</kbd> I am only given the option <kbd>Tiled</kbd>. This option does not work because it just splits the document across 4 pages instead of scaling it down to fit.

[This site](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.publisher/change-page-size-scale-page-to-new/139735) suggests to save as PDF then scale the PDF, but this seems a very poor option.

Answer (score 2):

To do a complete resize of a Publisher document and all objects in it:

1. Resize page to whatever size you want.  This will leave all objects larger than page.
2. Select all on page (Ctrl+A)
3. Right-click an oversized object and select Group.
4. Resize all objects together by just resizing the group.
5. Change font sizes, borders and effects as required.

Good LUCK!
-Thomas

Comment: Would you believe I actually answered this on the wrong question, but I think it still might be applicable.  Sorry. -Thomas

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have heard is to use the 'scale to fit' option.  However, I could not find that option on my Publisher '10.  I encountered this issue when attempting to print on A3 Landscape.  The image, although on an A3 page, scaled to the smaller A4 size.

The way I found to correct this was to go into PAGE DESIGN, select SIZE, and then select the appropriate size (A3 Landscape, for example).  Once I did this I was able to correctly scale the image as desired.

This same process should work for non-Australian sizes (Letter, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above helped or were easy enough to perform. So what I did was just circumvent re-sizing altogether. Just Print in A4, which is the correct size for me, just choose whatever you created it in by using a "print to PDF" print driver like “CutePDF writer” or “Microsoft Print to PDF”, there are plenty of free ones. This will create a PDF file.  Then print to A3 or again, whatever size you need using Adobe Acrobat reader with the Fit option ticked. Adobe Acrobat reader does the scaling very well. Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you’re saying. If other people can’t understand it either, then your answer won’t help anybody. Can you please [edit] your answer to describe what you did, step by step, in enough detail to allow somebody else to do the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

I use publisher to create accurate scale drawings showing measurements. Then PrintScreen, copy to (in my case) photoshop, crop what you want, save as png etc and print on A4 (or whatever).

Answer (score -1):

Best way I found to resize a Publisher document to print:
Export the document into a PDF by going to file, then export, then create PDF/XPS.

*It should create a PDF version of the document at its original size. If not, go to options in the files explorer before clicking OK, click on Print Options, and click on one page per sheet.

Open the PDF file, click on file, then click print.

Click on properties on the top.

Click on Paper/Quality tab and either choose a size under Paper sizes or click on custom below Paper sizes to set your own size. (Be sure to change the name if you clicked on Custom so you can print)

Click Print.

Comment: This seems somewhat similar to a couple of the other answers. Can you clarify how yours is different? What program do you open the PDF in?

Answer (score -2):

I am using MS Publisher 2016 from an active Office 365 subscription.

I have read this post and I believe that changing the source page size is WRONG. I have one page in Publisher set to poster A3, which I want to print to ALL the following: a big A3 poster, a regular A4 page as well as a small A5 leaflet. I do not want to manually resize all and scale fonts, etc. This is simply crazy.

The solution I have found is to design the page at the largest size, e.g., A3, export to PDF according to the page size. Then I import it into GIMP at 300 dpi, then go to image / scale and select "lock aspect ratio" and "cm" and then set the exact PAPER size I want for each one, I resize then I export to PDF or JPEG under a new file name.

GIMP imports all fonts and graphics and converts them to a single one page-sized bitmap, then scales it to either the medium A4 page or the smaller A5 leaflet.

Anyway I still find this totally CRAZY. Publisher shall have the option of SCALING THE SOURCE PAGE TO FIT THE TARGET PAPER as alternative to tiling.

Comment: This answer does not even attempt to answer the author's question.  It also appears you have your own question, since you are asking for our thoughts on something, but even if that type of question was allowed here at Superuser we couldn't answer it because you submitted your question as an answer to an answer